# Passing arrays as URL parameter JavaScript/GAS

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, javascript-objects, urlfetch

I have two functions.

One queries for project id, project name, and project status and saves them up in an array.This works fine.

```
function get_All_Projects() {
    var options = {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + tkft_token
        }
    };
    var url = tkft_url + endpoint + "auth=" + tkft_token + pages;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var info = JSON.parse(response);
    var content = info.data;    
    var project_arr = [];
    var identity = {};  
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        if (content.length > 0) {
            identity.Project_ID = content[i].id;
            identity.Project_Name = content[i].name;
            identity.Project_Start_Date = content[i].starts_at;
            identity.Project_End_Date = content[i].ends_at;
            identity.Project_Status = content[i].project_state; 
            project_arr.push(identity);
        }
    }
    //Logger.log(project_arr);
}
```

The second function is supposed to use the Id saved up in the project_arr so that I can get all users per project. The challenge is, I am having a hard time including one of the array objects in the URL for this function and also looping through every project id. I keep running into **Cannot read property 'length' of undefined** error, Is there something I am missing?

```
function get_By_Users(project_arr) {
    var options = {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tkft_token
        }
    };

    for (var i = 0; i<project_arr.length; i++) {  
        var url = tkft_url+ 'projects/'+ project_arr.Project_ID +'/users?auth='+ tkft_token + pages
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options); 
        var info= JSON.parse(response); 
        var content = info.data;
    }

    Logger.log(content);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `get_By_Users()`?

Comment: @TheMaster, not sure I understand your question, but to call for all users this is the URL structure **/api/v1/projects/<project_id>/users** Basically, I should get the **project_id** from  **project_arr* in  get_All_Projects() function and use it in the URL in the second function

Comment: If you're calling `get_By_Users()` outside of your `get_All_Projects()` function, `project_arr` **is undefined** since it is a local var.

Comment: @pistou Could you kindly guide me on how I can be able to make this Global var. I have declared the **var project_arr = [];** as a global variable but still running into the same error

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) and explain how you are calling this function.

Comment: Even though  you got a answer, this is basic stuff and it'll do you good if you read and practice basic functions link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am surprised that this code works with no Promises or async, if it really does a URL fetch. Or is that a mock?

Anyway, rather than a loop and Array.push, you can just use Array.map to do a data transform.

Also, you can use a template string, rather than string concatenation.

```
function get_All_Projects() {
    const options = {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + tkft_token
        }
    };
    const url = `${tkft_url}${endpoint}auth=${tkft_token}${pages}`
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const info = JSON.parse(response);
    const content = info.data;    
    const project_arr = content.map(item => ({
        Project_ID: item.id;
        Project_Name: item.name;
        Project_Start_Date: item.starts_at;
        Project_End_Date: item.ends_at;
        Project_Status: item.project_state; 
    }))
    return project_arr
}
```

Then you need to call `get_By_Users` with the `project_arr`:

```
const allProjects = get_All_Projects()
get_By_Users(allProjects)
```

This one flattens down even more with Array.map.

```
async function get_By_Users(project_arr) {
    var options = {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tkft_token
        }
    };

   const makeUrl = p => `${tkft_url}projects/${p.Project_ID}/users?auth=${tkft_token}${pages}`

  const safeJSONparse = item => {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(item)
    } catch (e) {
      return {data: undefined}
    }
  }

  const data = project_arr.map(p =>
     safeJSONparse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(makeUrl(p), options)).data))

    Logger.log(data);
}
```

You always need to try / catch with JSON.parse, because it throws if it can't parse the input. You then need to decide how your application will behave when this happens. 20% of coding is getting it to work. The other 80% is coding for what happens when it doesn't work.

See [this article](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/just-say-no-to-loops-and-variables/) for why to use Array.map, and [this one](https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/shun-the-mutant/) for why to use `const`.

Comment: *I am surprised that this code works with no Promises or async, if it really does a URL fetch.* See tag  [tag:urlfetch] info page

Comment: Interesting - I'd never seen that before.